# What's the best library for parsing RSS/Atom in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, rss, cpan, atom-feed

I notice that [XML::RSS::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-RSS-Parser/) hasn't been updated since 2005. Is this still the recommended library for parsing RSS or Atom? Is there a better one or a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure it's ever been the "recommended library". If I know which kind of feed I need to parse, I use [XML::RSS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-RSS/) or [XML::Atom](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Atom/) as appropriate, but if (as is more likely) I just know it's a web feed, I use [XML::Feed](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Feed/).

Adding an example of using XML::Feed as requested..

```
use XML::Feed;

my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(\$string_containing_feed);

foreach ($feed->entries) {
  print $_->title, "\n";
  print $_->content->body, "\n";
}
```

This is all pretty much copied from the module documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I actually like to avoid domain-specific XML parsers these days and just use XPath for everything. That way I only have to remember one API. (Unless it's a huge XML, then I'll use an event-based parser like [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/).)

So using  [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath), I can grab a bunch of stuff from an RSS file like this:

```
my $rss = get_rss();
my $xp = XML::XPath->new( xml => $rss );

my $stories = $xp->find( '/rss/channel/item' );

foreach my $story( $stories->get_nodelist ) {
    my $url   = $xp->find( 'link',  $story )->string_value;
    my $title = $xp->find( 'title', $story )->string_value;
    ...
}
```

Not the prettiest code in the world, but it works.

Comment: What are you feeding to XPath? a url or an XML file?

Answer (score 5):

If XML::RSS::Parser works for you then use it. I've used XML::Parser to deal with RSS but I had narrow requirements and XML::Parser was already installed.

Just because something has been updated in a few years doesn't mean that it doesn't work anymore; I don't think the various RSS/Atom specs have changed recently so there's no need for the parser to change.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a very nice module called `XML::FeedPP` (see http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-FeedPP/lib/XML/FeedPP.pm). `FeedPP` is no so fast but it writen in almost pure Perl and has minimalistic dependencies.