# Matching content between tags from RSS and inserting each match into an array - perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, rss, tags

I'm not sure how else to word what I want, so I'll just use examples for what I have and what I want.

I have:

```
my $rss = ("<item><title>this is a test title</title></item>
<item><title>this is also a test title</title></item>");
my @items = ($rss =~ /<item>[\s.*]<\/item>/g);
```

And what I'd like to end up with is this:

```
@items[0]:    <title>this is a title</title>
@items[1]:    <title>this is also a title</title>
```

I'd also like the regex to allow for new lines so that when I replace that test string with real RSS it will still work. I'm sure there is plenty that I'm doing wrong, but hours of searching has made me no closer to where I want to be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best library for parsing RSS/Atom in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974104/whats-the-best-library-for-parsing-rss-atom-in-perl)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but the answer is "use a module, as shown in the linked thread."

Comment: [The canonical answer to "how do I parse HTML with regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Your lecturers solution will work fine in most cases, but I feel obliged to point out that this will break on comments `<!--<item>foo</item>-->`, on XML namespaces `<rss:item>bar</rss:item>`, on CDATA sections containing <del>the tags</del> such a string, and on items with attributes.

Comment: Please, put the answer in an answer and not in the question and accept your own answer. Also, could you removed solved from the title at the same time. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered for more information!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The solution, as provided by my lecturer:**

```
my @items = ($rss =~ m{<item>(.*?)</item>}gs);
```

Comment: As indicated in comments to your question, your lecturer's solution is incorrect and breaks under various conditions.